# SD card not booting

Tags: boot

I have an issue with my initial boot. Indeed: I did it on a SD card and it seemed to have work as shown in the following picture:

[image: boot]

yet when I connect the Raspberry Pi with the card to the display screen with the HDMI wire I have a "no signal" message...

[image: no signal]

**What went wrong?**

#### My guess

I have read from [Getting Started with the Raspberry Pi](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=91&t=4751), on raspberrypi.org, that

*the red LED marked PWR will light (except for the zero). **The green LED marked OK (or ACK in later version) will blink in an irregular pattern to show whenever the Pi reads from the SD card.***

Yet this never occured on my Raspberry...

Furthermore, I wonder whether it is because when writing an image (eg using 'DD') I have to ensure that the destination is the entire card and not a partition on it. Indeed the few writing operations on the command line where:

```
dd bs=1M if=2016-03-18-raspbian-jessie.img of=/dev/devmmcblkop&

dd bs=1M if=2016-03-18-raspbian-jessie.img of=/dev/sd1&

sudo dd bs=1M if=2016-03-18-raspbian-jessie.img of=/dev/sd1&
```

Which one of the following commands would be most appropriate for writing to the sd card if any?

#### What I did

I first seach for the sda to umount:

Having:

```
/dev/mmcblk0p1   60M     0   60M   0% /media/antoine/BOOT
/dev/mmcblk0p2  3,6G  3,2G  215M  94% /media/antoine/e6e7f776-11a4-4cd7-b4fd-c44ecdbfcf90
```

I umounted mmcblk0p2
 and then tried again to give to the card the image.

```
:~$ sudo dd bs=1M if=2016-03-18-raspbian-jessie.img of=/dev/devmmcblkop
3847+0 records in
3847+0 records out
4033871872 bytes (4,0 GB) copied, 24,9113 s, 162 MB/s
```

Yet, once again the green light didn't blink and stayed on...

Comment: Is the HDMI cable connected (to the Pi and screen) before power on?

Comment: @SteveRobillard no, after having powered it

Comment: Try connecting the HDMI cable then powering up. By default if not connected on powerup it uses the composite video.

Comment: @SteveRobillard no signal, still...

Comment: have you tried using a different sd card? what files do you see when you open the scare up on a pc?

Comment: *"Yet this never occured on my Raspberry..."*  **So what did happen??**  Nothing, no lights?  I can see at least the red pwr is on.  If the the green light never came on and this is a A/B+, it has completely rejected the card -- as in it will do that with *no card at all*.  If it's a 2 and the green came on and stayed on, same thing.

Comment: @goldilocks no there is both green and red lights, it's a 2 and the green came on and stayed on. So it has completely rejected the card. I have to umount the card and try again.

Comment: *"I have to ensure that the destination is the entire card and not a partition on it."* -> **Yes.**  And don't throw it into the background with `&`. Just be patient and watch it complete.

Comment: @goldilocks I did it again (and updated to show you my attempt). Yet it remains green...

Comment: have you tried a different sd card?

Comment: @MohammadAli I don't have another SD card

Comment: can you show us the files that you see immediately when you `cd` the sd card?

Comment: @MohammadAli How do I do that? I can do `cd /dev` but not `cd /dev/mmcblk0p2` the only thing that looks like a card signature when I do `ls` is `devmmcblkop`. The rest is full of `tty...` or `ram...`

Comment: Can you please try again but by first by writing zeros over the sd card with the following command `sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdX bs=1k count=2048 ` then after ensuring that the sd card has been completely wiped. unmount the sd card using `sudo umount /dev/sda1`? then by writing with the command `sudo dd bs=1M if=2016-03-18-raspbian-jessie.img of=/dev/sd1&` and what is your output of lsusb?

Comment: @MohammadAli Sure! Yet it stoped after writing: `sudo umount /dev/sda1`

with the following error message:
`umount: /: device is busy.
        (In some cases useful info about processes that use
         the device is found by lsof(8) or fuser(1))
`

Comment: what is the output of lsusb?

Comment: `Bus 003 Device 005: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 0a5c:21d7 Broadcom Corp. BCM43142 Bluetooth 4.0
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 0bda:5756 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 8087:8001 Intel Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so as stated in the comments you mention that after writing all zeros to the sd card using the command

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdX bs=1k count=2048
```

You state that when trying to unmount your drive using the command

```
sudo umount /dev/sda1
```

that you get an error stating that the device is busy.
With this information I believe that a process is attempting to write to your sd card in the background which is preventing you from unmounting it and is also quite possibly corrupting your sd card write. If you could please now ensure that it is the correct sd card that you are writing to by removing the sd card and using the command

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

Then by connecting the sd card and retuning the command listed above that will be the name of your sd card (note the name may change with disconnects). To forcefully unmount the drive you may use the following command listed below:

```
fuser -km /dev/sda2
```

- k : Kill processes accessing the file.
- m : Name specifies a file on a mounted file system or a block device that is mounted. In above example you are using /dev/sda2

Note: The command above may need to be run with `sudo`
After your SD card has been successfully unmounted, use the command below to write your iso to your sd card.

```
dd bs=4M if=raspberrypi-img.iso of=/dev/sda2
```

`bs=4M` is optional. It stands for `Block Size` and is used to create larger blocks to write faster, if this does not work for you try `bs=1M`

Comment: Than you for considering my question. I did the command line you gave mequestion to show you them, and edited my , yet I'm nt sure of which `sda` is the one where the boot is set because of the `*`

Comment: What part are you stuck on, because you do not need the boot column days in any of this `sudo fdisk -l` to see which dev drive it is. Just run the command, without the Ed card or adapter plugged in.then plug the sd card and and see which new dev drive shows up. If you can't figure it out on your own just share what it says before and after you connect the drive and I'll try and help you figure out which drive it is.OH you many also be looking at the boot * which is the boot hdd and not the sd card

Comment: Please elaborate on which command you get stuck at and why

Comment: I just uploaded what I did with your advises. I think the new dev drive is `mmcblk0`.

Comment: You think what is?

Comment: I think the new dev drive is `mmcblk0`, I uploaded my attempt with your advise, still, it doesn't blink...

Comment: Can you tell me what `fdisk -l` says after you ran the commands above?

Comment: nothing. Yet it acually worked. My Raspberry started blinking and I have the desktop on my screen now!

Comment: That's great to hear! Best of luck with your Pi adventures

Answer (score 0):

I had this very same problem. I found that it was 3 things. First,  try using a different HDMI cable. Then,  try following the procedures to re-install the image to your SD card. You can find that on www.raspberrypi.org, and type into the search bar how to install the raspbian image. And if that doesn't work,  try changing out the PI unit. I have 3 RPI2B,  and I found out that the one I wanted to use was quite abused and contributed to my issues. Trying any one of these combinations will end up with a satisfactory result,  it's just time consuming. Your power source COULD be an issue too,  but I doubt it. However one whom, is prudent would check on that as well.